# Allow other JavaScript functions (including from other files) to "hook" into my function

Tags: javascript, hook

I feel like I'm overthinking this concept, but I'm stuck on it. Does JavaScript have the ability to allow other functions (from the same or different JS files) to hook into a function?

To clarify, if I create an array in a function I am writing is it possible to allow other JS files to hook into it to modify that array before I parse it? Or would I need to build some kind of system to manage all of the "hooks"? I'd like to avoid using a global window variable if possible, but that *would* work.

### Here's an example

For sake of argument, let's assume these run in the order I've listed them (ignore the race condition I've created here).

#### main.js

```js
var animals = ['cat', 'dog'];
animals = hookIntoThis(animals); //Allow other functions or files to add/modify animals to the array here
console.log(animals); //--> "cat", "dog", "elephant"
```

`hookIntoThis()` is not actually a reference to anything- that would just be where I'd want to let other functions/files (if they exist) modify the array.

#### other.js

```js
function addMoreAnimals(animals){ //This would somehow listen for that hook from main.js
    animals.push('elephant');
    animals.push('lion');

    return animals;
}
```

#### whatever.js

```js
function noLions(animals){ //This would also hook into that function from main.js to modify the array
    if ( animals.indexOf('lion') >= 0 ){
        animals.splice(animals.indexOf('lion'), 1); //Just for the sake of example
    }

    return animals;
}
```

At first I was thinking a custom DOM event/listener would work, but that is (as far as I know) a one-way thing. I could trigger, and even pass the animals array to the DOM event, but unless I use a global window variable I couldn't get any data *back*.

I apologize if this is an overly simple concept and/or a duplicate question. I did search around quite a bit before posting this.

Comment: Based on your `main.js` example, you are not exactly "hooking", you are only reassigning new array to the same variable. So what you explained above is entirely doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom event listener is the right one, I think, if `main` doesn't know which other modules are going to be modifying `animals`.

If you know that all hooks will be executed synchronously, you can have `main` do its main work (after modification) in a microtask, once the main thread has finished, eg:

```js
// main.js
let modifiableAnimals = ['cat', 'dog'];
window.addEventListener('customHook', ({ detail: modifyFn }) => {
  modifiableAnimals = modifyFn(modifiableAnimals);
});
Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => {
    console.log(modifiableAnimals);
  });

// other.js
window.dispatchEvent(
  new CustomEvent(
    'customHook',
    {
      detail: (animals) => {
        animals.push('elephant');
        animals.push('lion');
        return animals;
      }
    }
  )
);

// whatever.js
window.dispatchEvent(
  new CustomEvent(
    'customHook',
    {
      detail: (animals) => {
        if ( animals.indexOf('lion') >= 0 ){
          animals.splice(animals.indexOf('lion'), 1); //Just for the sake of example
        }
        return animals;
      }
    }
  )
);
```

If you know that the existing array is only going to be *mutated* (and doesn't have to be reassigned), you can simplify it a bit:

```js
// main.js
const modifiableAnimals = ['cat', 'dog'];
window.addEventListener('customHook', ({ detail: modifyFn }) => {
  modifyFn(modifiableAnimals);
});
Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => {
    console.log(modifiableAnimals);
  });

// other.js
window.dispatchEvent(
  new CustomEvent(
    'customHook',
    {
      detail: (animals) => {
        animals.push('elephant');
        animals.push('lion');
      }
    }
  )
);

// whatever.js
window.dispatchEvent(
  new CustomEvent(
    'customHook',
    {
      detail: (animals) => {
        if ( animals.indexOf('lion') >= 0 ){
          animals.splice(animals.indexOf('lion'), 1); //Just for the sake of example
        }
      }
    }
  )
);
```

This is still kind of weird to do though, IMO. If possible, I'd consider having something *else* interface with `main.js` and the other files, and call `main.js` functions with the handlers instead:

```js
// main.js
function changeAnimals(...changeFns) {
  const modifiableAnimals = ['cat', 'dog'];
  changeFns.forEach(fn => fn(modifiableAnimals));
  console.log(modifiableAnimals);
}

// other.js
const pushElephantAndLion = (animals) => {
  animals.push('elephant');
  animals.push('lion');
};

// whatever.js
const removeOneLion = (animals) => {
  if ( animals.indexOf('lion') >= 0 ){
    animals.splice(animals.indexOf('lion'), 1); //Just for the sake of example
  }
};

// *actual* main code:
changeAnimals(pushElephantAndLion, removeOneLion);
```

Comment: Thanks for this- I think this is exactly what I was looking for.